# Failed to clone private github repositories on a readthedocs local server

Tags: django-allauth, read-the-docs

I have installed a [readthedocs local server](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) but **I am unable to build private github repositories from my organization** through **django-allauth**.

I have admin privileges in all repositories, and I have configured django-allauth in the admin panel:

- Adding the **Client ID** and **Secret key** to `"admin/socialaccounts/socialapplications"`.
- Adding an **access Token** into `"admin/socialaccounts/socialtoken"`.
- Adding the following configuration to the `"admin/oauth/remoterepository"`

[image]

Every time I try to build the repository I get the following error:

```
Failed to import project: Failed to get code from 'https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git' (git clone): 128 git 
clone error output: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Does somebody know why is this happening? has somebody been able to configure a local readthedocs server in a similar scenario, using private repositories within an organization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue adding the flag:

```
ALLOW_PRIVATE_REPOS = True
```

Into my settings file **my-project/readthedocs/settings/local_settings.py**. This will activate **x-oauth-basic** urls for the Github repositories, allowing me to use my Github personal access token to clone the repository. I have just updated the **Repository clone url** field on **admin/oauth/remoterepository** using the following format:

```
https://<your token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/my-organization/my-project.git
```